# Downloaded client's distribution certificate, but it isn't showing up in my keychain

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, keychain

Im not sure why my client's distribution certificate isn't showing up on my keychain.Any suggestions or solutions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double-click on a certificate file in order to add it to your keychain. In order to actually use the certificate (alongside the required provisioning profiles) you'll also need the public/private keys used to generate it.

Comment: Make sure you've got the public/private keys first.